# How to merge 2 lines into 1 in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Lets say i have got a sample of data looks like that:

```
   Rzecz
   +subst:sg:nom:f
   dzieje
   +subst:pl:nom:n
   się
   +qub
   w
   +prep:acc:nwok
   Paryżu
   +subst:sg:loc:m3
   ,
   +interp
   w
   +prep:acc:nwok
```

and as a result i want it to look like that:

```
   Rzecz+subst:sg:nom:f
   dzieje+subst:pl:nom:n
   się+qub
   w+prep:acc:nwok
   Paryżu+subst:sg:loc:m3
   ,+interp
   w+prep:acc:nwok
```

How can i achive this in notepad++?
I was trying to find "\r\n+" and replace it with "+" cuz i found a similar thread but that solution doesnt work for me.
Could u pls help me:>

Comment: use a macro instead, is more appropriate for your use case. Let me know if you can't it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: `\R\h*(?=[+])` Replace by: `(nothing)`

Remember to tick "Regular expression" on the replace box.

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/QoxQMM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

the example you list is using regular expressions.
Ctl+H takes you to the search window

enter that line in the replace field and click on Search mode Regular expressions.

See if it works then.

Edit:
the closest I got:

```
    Find what:(.+)\R *(.*)  
    Replace with: \1\2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `+` and the `newline` before that, and then while those are selected press CTRL+H to enter the replace/find window. Then check the `Extended` option in the bottom left (as in the image) so that it recognizes the `\n` and `\r` characters. Type a single `+` in the `replace with` field and then replace all.

You also can hold the CTRL key and click before all `+` to add a caret before every one of them. Then simply press `Backspace` to remove the `newline`. But this is not practical if there are lots of lines

[image: Check the <code>Extended</code> option]